# Number format issue in continuous counter

Tags: jquery, counter

For some reason my continuous counter correctly shows the initial starting number, '65,000', with the thousands separator, but after that it fails to add the 200 increment to the starting number, on each count.  What I want to see is

```
65,000, 65,200, 65,400, etc
```

I suspect I'm still using my thousands separator formatting function 'numberWithCommas' wrongly.  I've tried to call it from a number of other places in the code, but nothing works.  I'm also confused on how to adapt previous posts into this code. Bit out of my depth here.  Can anyone help?  https://jsfiddle.net/cs6hL4jy/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var StartNowTonnes = 6500000
  var timeVal = StartNowTonnes;

  $('.timer').html(timeVal);
  refreshTimer(); // Load timer function

  var timerInterval = 1000;
  var loadTimer = setInterval(refreshTimer, timerInterval);
});

//----------------------------

// FUNCTION Refresh Timer
function refreshTimer() {
  // Set counter
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Get timer value
    var myTime = parseInt($('.timer').html()) + 5;

    // If timer has not reached 0
    if (myTime > 0) {

      //$('.timer').html(myTime);
      var myTimeWithComma = numberWithCommas(myTime);
      $('.timer').html(myTimeWithComma);


    } else {
      $('.timer').html('Time up!');
    }
  }, 1);

}

//--------

function numberWithCommas(number) {
  var parts = number.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return parts.join(".");
}
```

```css
.timer {
  background: #d2d8e8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer"></div>
```

Comment: All the problems you have are caused by mixing concepts of views and models. The thing is, you don't need commas in your `timer` value (model) - you need only number. And you only need to mutate (add 200) to that number. At the same time, you need commas only to represent (view) that number.

Comment: Oh dear.  Are you suggesting I rip up and start again?

Comment: Why do you have a condition that "time is up", when you actually increase? And why your code increases the value with 5, when you want to increase it with 200? Why do you have both `setInterval` and `setTimeout`?

Comment: Err... fair enough, I'll take out the 'time is up'.  As for the other questions, just as @raina77ow said, this is a mix of stuff I tried to combine.  I honestly thought I was increasing by 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not read the current value from the page back into a variable. Instead keep the value in memory (i.e. maintain *state*). Your current problem is that parseInt will not interpret the number as you expect. But that problem becomes irrelevant if you don't have a dependency on parsing that number. You generated it yourself, so keep track of it. Also:

- You don't need both `setInterval` and `setTimeout`
- It is strange that you *increase* the number and still check whether the number is positive as if it were a count-down.
- Your code increments with 5, not with 200
- Comments can be helpful, but avoid putting comments that add no information at all. Like "// FUNCTION Refresh Timer" is really not telling anything useful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var state = {
      timerInterval: 1000,
      myTime: 6500000,
      increment: 200
  };

  refreshTimer(state);
});

function refreshTimer(state) {
    var myTimeWithComma = numberWithCommas(state.myTime);
    $('.timer').html(myTimeWithComma);
    
    // If timer has not reached 0
    if (state.myTime > 0) {
        state.myTime += state.increment;
        setTimeout(() => refreshTimer(state), state.timerInterval);
    } else {
        $('.timer').html('Time up!');
    }
}

//--------

function numberWithCommas(number) {
  var parts = number.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return parts.join(".");
}
```

```css
.timer {
  background: #d2d8e8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Goodness me, going through this code I'm actually understanding things for the first time now.  Very much appreciate your help. Much clearer.